# How to set the default number of decimals in excel while exporting data from my web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a page where there is only a little data displayed in grids & charts under different tabs, but i have an 'exporttoexcel' button in each tab which exports the entire data(which is huge) into the Ms-Excel.

In the charts and grids i am displaying data up-to 2 decimal places though i am obtaining the entire data(with all decimals, 18 to be precise) from the database. I am doing this by using the 'dataformatstring','displayformat' properties and so on.

Now the requirement I am looking for is,

When I am exporting the data into excel, there is an option in excel to increase/decrease decimals. Is there a way that I can pass a parameter and set the decrease decimals to some value(Ex:4 decimals)?

P.s: For exporting data to excel I am using a dll provided by our development team which supports our requirements.

```
 public class ExcelExporter
{
    public ExcelExporter();

    public void ExportDataGrid(DataGrid dgExport, string FileName);
    public void ExportDataGrid(GridView dgExport, string FileName);
    public void ExportDataSet(DataSet DataSet, string ExcelFileName);
    public void ExportToDataTable(DataTable dt, string ExcelFileName);
    public void ExportToDataTable1(DataTable dt, string name);
}

public void ExportToDataTable(DataTable dt, string ExcelFileName)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename=" + ExcelFileName);
        this.WriteWorkbookHeader();
        this.WriteTable(dt);
        this.WriteWorkbookFooter();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
private void WriteTable(DataTable table)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Worksheet ss:Name='" + table.TableName + "'>\r\n");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=\"" + (object)table.Columns.Count + "\" ss:ExpandedRowCount=\"" + (object)(table.Rows.Count + 1) + "\" x:FullColumns=\"1\" x:FullRows=\"1\">\r\n");
        this.WriteTableHeader(table);
        this.WriteTableRows(table);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>\r\n");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Worksheet>\r\n");
}
```

This is the method in which the datatable is being written to the excel 
And

I am sure that this can be done by formatting data-table that is being passed to the ExcelExporter.ExportToDataTable, i.e. using string.Format("{0:n0}",datacolumns).

But the reason I want it to be configured with the Excel(Decrease Decimal) feature is because in Excel if you observe, the value displayed in the cell is in decreased decimal, but the actual value is retained(see the formula bar). This feature actually helps while writing formulae while calculating, as the calculations are done on the actual value rather than the decreased decimal value.

Hope my point is clear and valid.